# What is the chance that more than one from 20 random screws will be defected, if the chance that a screw is defected is $0,015$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Ok, for this problem I need to use one of the distribution formulas, but am not even sure which one. I am thinking that Geometrical distribution formula could be useful $f(x)=p\cdot q^{x-1}$ as it determines the chance that the event happens at a certain attempt. So, I would calculate the chance that the screw is defected at $x=20, $ but then the calculation gives me extremely small numbers and I assume it is wrong choice. But am not sure why. Then Binomial distribution maybe would be helpful? Should I sum all the chances from 0 to 20 that the screw is defected? Maybe there is an easier way? I am completely lost.

Comment: It would be nice if you mark answers as accepted. It shows that you appreciate people who took time to answer your questions.

Comment: Suggestion: a Poisson distribution might be appropriate here.

Comment: @callculus  I must to accept every half-arsed answer?  Awkward had a good suggestion, shame I didn't follow up on him.

Comment: @user But what about the other answers. For instance I gave a an answer here. And no reaction from your side. What´s wrong with the answers?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with geometric distribution. Geometric distribution answers the questions of how many trials is required until the first success. It can take arbitary positive integer.

For this question, we are interested in how many defective screw are there out of $20$. The right distribution is indeed binomial distribution. The defective one need not be the last screw.