# Need to find a $n=4$ and $k=3$ term of Taylor expansion for a given function.

Tags: taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

Here is the function:

$$f(x,y)=e^{xy}sin(x^2y), \ \ M=\left[\begin{matrix}1 \\ \pi \end{matrix}\right], n=4, k=3$$

$$f(x,y)= {\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}} \left[ \left(\begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix}\right)\left. \frac{\partial f}{ \partial x^{n-k}\partial y^k }\right\vert_{M} (x-x_0)^{n-k}(y-y_0)^k \right]$$

My solution:

$$f_x=ye^{xy}sin(x^2y) + 2xe^{xy}cos(x^2y)$$

$$f_{xy}=e^{xy}sin(x^2y)+xye^{xy}sin(x^2y)+ x^2ye^{xy}cos(x^2y)+2x^2e^{xy}cos(x^2y)-2x^3e^{xy}sin(x^2y)$$

$$f_{xyy}=xe^{xy}sin(x^2y)+x^2e^{xy}cos(x^2y)+xe^{xy}sin(x^2y)+x^2ye^{xy}sin(x^2y)+x^3ye^{xy}cos(x^2y)+x^2e^{xy}cos(x^2y)+x^3ye^{xy}cos(x^2y)-x^4ye^{xy}sin(x^2y)+2x^3e^{xy}cos(x^2y)-2x^4e^{xy}sin(x^2y)-2x^4e^{xy}sin(x^2y)-2x^5e^{xy}cos(x^2y)$$

$$f_{xyyy}=x^2e^{xy}sin(x^2y)+x^3e^{xy}cos(x^2y)+x^3e^{xy}cos(x^2y)-x^4e^{xy}sin(x^2y)+x^2e^{xy}sin(x^2y)+x^3e^{xy}cos(x^2y)+x^2e^{xy}sin(x^2y)+x^3ye^{xy}sin(x^2y)+x^4ye^{xy}cos(x^2y)+x^3e^{xy}cos(x^2y)+x^4ye^{xy}cos(x^2y)-x^5ye^{xy}sin(x^2y)+x^3e^{xy}cos(x^2y)-x^4e^{xy}sin(x^2y)+x^3e^{xy}cos(x^2y)+x^4ye^{xy}cos(x^2y)-x^5ye^{xy}sin(x^2y)-x^4e^{xy}sin(x^2y)-x^5ye^{xy}sin(x^2y)-x^6ye^{xy}cos(x^2y)+2x^4e^{xy}cos(x^2y)-2x^5e^{xy}sin(x^2y)-2x^5e^{xy}sin(x^2y)-2x^6e^{xy}cos(x^2y)-2x^5e^{xy}sin(x^2y)-2x^6e^{xy}cos(x^2y)-2x^6e^{xy}cos(x^2y)+2x^7e^{xy}sin(x^2y)$$

So, I know that it is possible to write it in a shorter way, but I don't know how. Because for me it looks so messy the way I did it. 
So then: $$f(1,\pi)= \frac{4!}{3!}\cdot( e^{\pi}+ e^{\pi}+e^{\pi}+\pi e^{\pi}+e^{\pi}+\pi e^{\pi}+e^{\pi}+e^{\pi}+\pi e^{\pi}-\pi e^{\pi}+2e^{\pi}-2e^{\pi}-2e^{\pi})= 6 \cdot (4\pi +\pi e^{\pi})$$

So, the Taylor expansions term that corresponds to given $n$ and $k$ is:
$$6\cdot(4\pi + \pi e^{\pi})(x-1)(x-\pi)^3$$

Any feedback would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you think you get an answer? See my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3423726/what-is-the-chance-that-more-than-one-from-20-random-screws-will-be-defected-if#comment7040899_3423726) Good luck. In general any reply would be helpful. :)

Comment: @callculus That's not true, if the one who answers says the same thing that I said in the thread ( that I should probably use binomial), then I don't see how it is of any help to understand the problem at hand.

Comment: Check the other answers as well please. It is really disappointing if someone takes time to post an comment/answer and he/she gets no feedback.

Comment: @callculus Ok, I will check.

Comment: That´s fair, user.

Comment: @callculus Can you help me? I am quite sure that derivatives themselves are correct, am not only sure whether these are the derivatives that are needed. And also about the Taylor expansion term. Whether that is correct.

Comment: I´m not sure. It looks very laborious. Maybe the calculation can be reduced by using $\sin(\pi)=0$ and $\cos(\pi)=-1$

Comment: @callculus You don't know how to do these type of problems?

Comment: That´t my problem as well. Sorry. I´m wondering that nobody else of the hundreds (?) of users has made a comment or posted an answer. But I have the feeling there maybe exists a kind of trick due the relations I´ve posted in my previous comment.